# Angular 2 sub child routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have been trying child routing in Angular 2.

And below is Route configuration

```
@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, useAsDefault: true },
{ path: '/vehicles/...', name: 'Vehicles', component: VehiclesComponent },
{ path: '/characters/...', name: 'Characters', component: CharactersComponent },
{ path: '/students/...', name: 'Students', component: StudentsComponent },
{ path: '/feecollection/...', name: 'Feecollection', component:FeeCollectionComponent}
])
export class AppComponent {
   public menuItems = [
   { caption: 'Dashboard', link: ['Dashboard'] },
   { caption: 'Characters', link: ['Characters'] },
   { caption: 'Vehicles', link: ['Vehicles'] },
   { caption: 'FKS-Dashboard', link: ['Dashboard'] },
   { caption: 'Students', link: ['Students'] },
   { caption: 'Fees', link: ['Vehicles'] },
   { caption: 'FeeCollection', link: ['Feecollection']}  
];
```

I have the problem with FeeCollection Component rest of them or working fine.
Here is FeeCollection Component

```
@Component({
selector: 'story-feecollection',
templateUrl: './app/fee/fee-collection.component.html',
providers: [FeeAPIService, ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
{path: '/batch', name: 'Batch', component: BatchComponent, useAsDefault:true},
{path: '/bystudent', name: 'Bystudent', component:ByStudentComponent}
])
export class FeeCollectionComponent{}
```

Here is my fee-collection component HTML page

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="" [routerLink]= "['Batch']">Batch</a></li>
                <li><a href="" [routerLink]="['Bystudent']">By Student</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
<div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
```

After navigating to FeeCollection I am getting the following error message in the browser console

```
EXCEPTION: Component "AppComponent" has no route named "Batch". in [['Batch'] in FeeCollectionComponent@20:35]
```

Comment: what version of Angular2/Router you are using?

Comment: I think I am using the latest version only. There is no dependency in the package.json file

Comment: Please add content of package.json

Comment: `"dependencies": {
    "a2-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.10"
   
  
     },
     "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^0.7.12",
    "fs-extra": "^0.24.0",
    "globby": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.0.0",
    "minimatch": "^2.0.10",
    "q": "^1.4.1"
     }`

Comment: Try using alpha, angular has come long way from beta..

Comment: Read more here, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html